# Reset a Variable that stores the number of times a Query runs back to 1 when the Count reaches a certain number?

Tags: sql, sql-server, limit, reset

I have a variable that stores the number of times a query runs, but it has a length limitation of 3 characters, which I can't modify. As such, once the Count reaches 999, I assume the logic will fail.

```
SET @QueryCount = (
    SELECT COUNT(1) FROM dbo.Records WHERE QueryName = @QueryName
);
```

Currently I have no logic to account for a Count that is over 3 characters, and the expectation is that the Variable will be reset to a Count of 1 once it reaches 999.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try and do integer division:

```
SET @QueryCount = (
    SELECT COUNT(1) - COUNT(1) / 1000 * 1000
    FROM dbo.Records 
    WHERE QueryName = @QueryName
);
```

This garantees that the value will belong to range `0..999`. When the value reaches `1000`, it resets to `0`.

**[Demo of the arithmetic logic](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=9c8ef740f1819fb1dd2753fde5c9b597)**:

```
DECLARE @value int = 999
SELECT @value - @value / 1000 * 1000
```

Yieds: `999`

```
DECLARE @value int = 1000
SELECT @value - @value / 1000 * 1000
```

Yields: `0`

```
DECLARE @value int = 3525
SELECT @value - @value / 1000 * 1000
```

Yields: `525`

Answer (score 0):

Or just:

`SELECT @value % 1000;`